# Python tkinter function that makes a rectangle does not define when doing w.coords

Tags: python, tkinter

my title might be a little confusing but basically I have a function that makes a rectangle in tkinter python.

```
w = Canvas()
def rectangle(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill):
    w.create_rectangle(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill=fill)
return;
```

so I have this.
It works if I try it on the canvas.
Now I want to move it.

```
test = rectangle(1,1,20,20,"blue")
```

this also works
but if I do

```
print(w.coords(test))
```

I get an error message saying that there is no value for it, and if I print just the plain variable out it says its

```
none
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function will return `None` by default. I don't understand what you want to do by using `return;` after the function definition, but I think this is what you want:

```
w = Canvas()
def rectangle(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill):
    return w.create_rectangle(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill=fill)
```

Hope it helps.